# element in my $scope variable won't get display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nginx

I just deployed a website to test in "production" but when i try to go to the website some of my computer won't see one the results of my ng-repeat and some will see. If I go to the website when there's nothing displayed I look at the source code and I see the ng-repeat with each object of my array, but no html output on the screen. Here some of my code when I load my controller:

```
/**
 * Function that send a request to get a list of posts.
 * @return {Function} A promise.
 */
function retrievePosts() {
    var defered = $q.defer();
    // If the user is logged in we do a search by country, otherwise we get all the posts.
    if($rootScope.user !== null && $rootScope.user !== undefined) {
        PostService.searchPost({ countries: [$rootScope.user.country] }, function(err, posts) {
            if(err) {
                defered.reject(err);
            }
            else if(posts && posts.length > 0) {
                defered.resolve(posts);
            } 
            // If the previous condition is not true, we try to get all the posts, since the search by country didn't work.
            else {

                 PostService.getAllPosts(function(err, posts2) {
                    if(err) {
                        defered.reject(err);
                    } else {
                        defered.resolve(posts2);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    } else {
        PostService.getAllPosts(function(err, posts) {
            if(err) {
                defered.reject(err);
            } 
            else {
                defered.resolve(posts);
            }
        });
    }
    return defered.promise;
}
```

This function is used to get an array of JSON posts object. Then I do a q.all like this:

```
$q.all([retrieveManufacturer(), retrieveCategories(), retrievePosts(), getTotalPosts(), retrieveGalleryPosts()]).then(function(results) {
    $scope.manufacturers = results[0];
    $scope.categories = results[1];

    // Here we must cache the result and slice it, so that angular doesn't render 
    // a tone of post but 10 at a time.
    postCache = results[2];
    $scope.numberOfPostsToShow = 10;
    $scope.posts = postCache.slice(0, $scope.numberOfPostsToShow);

    // Some code to display the proper amount of post for each category.
    var i = -1;
    var max = results[3].length;
    var groupedPostsCount = { };
    var group;

    while(++i < max) {
        group = results[3][i];

        // "_id" contains the name of the category.
        groupedPostsCount[group._id] =  group.count;
    }

    if(Object.keys(groupedPostsCount).length > 0){
        $scope.categoriesPostCount = groupedPostsCount;
    }

    $scope.galleryPosts = results[4];

    // Prepare the $scope.galleryPosts to be bound with posts.
    buildGallery($scope.galleryPosts);

}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Every task in $q.all gets executed and they all get resolved. I see them in my HTML like the categories, manufacturers, etc... Results[2] which are the array of posts are not null they really do have 500 posts in them. I try to call $scope.$apply() after buildGallery() method call, but nothing work. If I print {{ posts }} anywhere in my html i see the array of posts. But when they are in that ng-repeat:

```
<div class="ad-container" ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-click="viewPostDetails(post)">
                    <div class="ad-picture">
                        <table class="wrapper">
                            <tr>
                                <td><img ng-src="img/175/{{ post.mainImageName || post.imgUrls[0] }}" alt="No image provided"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ad-info">
                        <span class="ad-info-title">{{ post.title }}</span>
                        <span class="ad-info-price">{{ post.country == 'Canada' ? (post.price | currency : "CA$") : (post.price | currency : "US$") }}</span>

                        <br />
                        <span>{{ post.country }}, {{ post.province }}, {{ post.createdAt | date }}</span>

                        <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Of course this code is inside a div that has a controller bound to it.Like I said, it's really weird. On my development computer everything works perfectly, but some of the computers of my friend did work and others didn't. Here's the link to the website www.firearmsbin.com maybe the problem will occur on your computer. I tried on firefox, firefox for dev, edge, chrome and IE11.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was adblock who was not displaying my div which as the class "ad-container". So every class in css that contains "ad" word get block.